# Vim custom keybinding conventions?

Tags: vim

In Emacs, key sequences beginning with `C-c` are, by convention, reserved for individual users to set.  I think there is at least one more convention, too.

What, if any, are Vim's conventions for custom key bindings?

Answer (score 3):

You can use commands prefixed with your `<leader>` key as a convention to separate your own individual keymaps from default ones.

Set your `<leader>` key with a like this in your .vimrc file:

```
let mapleader = "_"
```

Then you can create key mappings that are prefixed with whatever you set your leader to like this:

```
nnoremap <leader><space> :noh<cr>
```

For more info see [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_3%29#Map_leader)

Comment: @Conner - That mostly depends on where they're from, what on their keyboard layout. For example, in my case (Croatian layout) a \ would be very inconvenient, since it requires the usage of a shift key. A comma is rather popular in these parts just because.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs, I would't say it was so much of a a convention, as much of a popular choice.

In Vim there is not even that, and although Ctrl+something or the F keys are popular, it is far from being a wide spread "convention".

A lot of Vim users just use the default "letter operations" in normal mode, with which they accomplish in text editing, what a majority of Emacs users must depend on functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a backslash which does nothing by default, only being the default value of mapping leader (both mapleader and maplocalleader). This leader is used in plugins and I strongly suggest to leave it for them only, using keys that have default actions attached, but that are not much useful. Common keys are `,` (repeats t/T/f/F motion in the opposite direction) and `_` (moves one line downward, on the first non-blank character), you can also check which ones you don’t use (I, for example, don’t use `+` and `-`, latter is good replacement for `_`). The reasons why I unlike @stonesam92 suggest not to set mapleader to them and instead put your own leader in your mappings directly are the following:

1. It makes plugins possibly add mappings conflicting with your own ones.
2. You get used to typing `,a`, `_a` or whatever, not to `<Leader>a`.
3. It makes mapping commands work differently depending on their location in the vimrc (`<Leader>` is computed only once, if you change mapleader afterwards already defined mappings won’t change).
4. It obfuscates the reading: you have to always remember, what `<Leader>` is.

If you are writing plugin, always use `<Leader>` and also leave the user the better way to customize them, two common solutions are using global options and using `hasmapto`:

```
" Global option
if !exists('g:plugin_mapping_key')
    let g:plugin_mapping_key='<Leader>a'
endif
execute 'nnoremap '.g:plugin_mapping_key.' :DoSomething<CR>'

" hasmapto
nnoremap <Plug>PluginDoSomething :DoSomething<CR>
if !hasmapto('<Plug>PluginDoSomething', 'n', 0)
    nmap <Leader>a <Plug>PluginDoSomething
endif
```